# Caron key on Ubuntu 16.04 prints subscript 5 after small delay

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, special-characters

Freshly installed system. On key with characters +ˇ=´ I am able to use caron with Shift key (it's ˇ, e.g. with Slovak layout), but if second key is pressed too late, it just writes ₅ before it. Same on different layouts and their variations (English too) and what's interesting, previous installation of 16.04 was fine...

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. Are you able to reproduce it yourself after a reboot?

Comment: Yes. It can be partially fixed by setting LC_CTYPE to e.g. sk_SK.UTF-8, then it changes sub five to correct letter after pressing second key, but why is it doing that in the first place?

Comment: I didn't realize that the locale may have anything to do with it. Maybe your locale is broken somehow. Can you please run the `locale` command and show us the output by editing your question.

Comment: Sorry, I already don't have this setup... If I will come to this situation in the future, I will post output here.